# jQuery overwrite function after page loaded

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have in page.js :

```
$(document).on("ready page:change", function() {
  x_function(2);
});
```

So x_function with param is executed after document is ready. But now, I want to overwrite this function from html file when

```
!user_sign_in?
```

but I can't. How can I do it. Set $(document).on("ready") in html and make some timer for execute , is this good solution?

Comment: `!user_sign_in?` javascript function?

Comment: Can we have more details, it's hard to figure out what you are actually trying to achieve here.

you could set it to a variable and then change the variable definition. Javascript doesn't support multiple definitions of the same function name.

var x_function = function(){}

later... 
if(typeof x_function === "function"){
    x_function = function(param){
       
    }
}